# C++: How to create a temporary object, containing a pointer - const or non-const, depending on context?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I want to hold some structures `Data` in a vector. These structures reference other ones by indices (instead of pointers), to conserve memory and make serialization easier. To follow these indices, I created a class `DataView`, which provides a comfortable interface for it. It looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Data
{
    int id_next;
    int id_prev;
    int value;
};

class Foo;

class DataView
{
    Foo * foo;
    int index;
public:
    DataView( Foo * foo_, int index_ )
        : foo( foo_ ), index( index_ )
    {
    }
    DataView next() const;
    DataView prev() const;
    int value() const;
    int & value();
    int id() const
    {
        return index;
    }
};

class Foo
{
    std::vector<Data> data;
public:
    friend class DataView;

    DataView dataview( int index )
    {
        return DataView( this, index );
    }

    Foo()
    {
        data.resize( 5 );
        for ( int i = 0; i < (int)data.size(); i++ )
        {
            data[i].id_next = (i + 1) % data.size();
            data[i].id_prev = (i + 4) % data.size();
            data[i].value = i * i;
        }
    }

    void write_cycle( int start_index ) // const
    {
        DataView seek = dataview( start_index );
        do
        {
            std::cout << "index " << seek.id() << " value " << seek.value() << std::endl;
            seek = seek.next();
        } while ( seek.id() != start_index );
    }
};

DataView DataView::next() const
{
    return DataView( foo, foo->data[index].id_next );
}
DataView DataView::prev() const
{
    return DataView( foo, foo->data[index].id_prev );
}
int DataView::value() const
{
    return foo->data[index].value;
}
int & DataView::value()
{
    return foo->data[index].value;
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.write_cycle( 3 );
    foo.dataview( 2 ).value() = 11;
    foo.write_cycle( 3 );
    return 0;
}
```

The problem arises if I have to differentiate between const and non-const variations of `dataview` method. In fact, `write_cycle` should be const, as it doesn't change anything. However, I get compiler error if I uncomment `const` qualifier.

error: passing ‘const Foo’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

How to write `DataView` containing const or non-const `foo` pointer, depending on whether its constructor was called with const or non-const pointer?

Comment: This design has so many red sirens going off....

Comment: Throw the asker a bone, @ChristopherPisz , and outline a few.

Comment: Well, for one, DataView is not an "Interface" to it, it is another class that has now become tightly coupled to Foo. More than that you've now got a friend relationship just to make it work. In fact, the data, that 
DataView is acting on, lives in Foo. A class should contain, manage, and act on, and own, its own data, in my book.  If you've got some class doing things with some other class' data, usually something is wrong.

Comment: It's not clear what the author is trying to accomplish big picture, beyond creating a collection of something and serializing it, but I'd bet a dollar there is a better design for the big picture problem.

Comment: Since we are wrapping an std::vector, usually the pattern I see, is that the wrapper implements a begin and end iterator, perhaps a size method, and those just call vector's methods. This way your collection class can be used just like any STL collection and with the STL algorithms.

Comment: This is not a simple wrapping. The real Foo class is far more complex, and this std::vector is just one of its internal collections. I reduced it to make a clear example.

Answer (score 5):

You said:

> These structures reference other ones by indices (instead of pointers), to conserve memory and make serialization easier. To follow these indices, I created a class `DataView`, which provides a comfortable interface for it.

That indicates to me that you should not need to support:

```
foo.dataview( 2 ).value() = 11;
```

Use `DataView` to only *read* the data. If you agree with that, you can change `DataView` to store a `Foo const*`. You can then get rid of  the non-`const` version of `DataView::value()`.

```
class DataView
{
    Foo const* foo;
    int index;
public:
    DataView( Foo const* foo_, int index_ )
        : foo( foo_ ), index( index_ )
    {
    }
    DataView next() const;
    DataView prev() const;
    int value() const;

    // Don't need this.
    // int & value();

    int id() const
    {
        return index;
    }
};
```

Comment: But I need DataView also to write the data. So basically I need it both const and non-const.

Comment: @longstar, yes. That's analogous to containers supporting `iterator` and `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 4):

If a method is `const`, then nothing it does or provides can be be allowed to change the instance. This includes any functions or other methods the method calls, and references to any members that the method returns must be `const` so they can't be used to modify the object in the future.

So if `write_cycle` is `const` then `dataview` must be `const` and `DataView` must have a constructor that accepts `const Foo *`. And this means `DataView::foo` must also be `const` to accept assignment of a `const Foo *`. This could be a problem if `DataView`'s clients expect to manipulate the stored `Foo`.

End result, `write_cycle` can't be `const` without a bunch of extra work.

Answer (score 0):

To add to user `R Sahu's` answer about leaving `Foo` within `Dataview` as `const` since it will act as a `read only` class and shouldn't modify `Foo`; you can add this function into `Foo's` class to update its values:

```
void Foo::updateValue( int index, const int& value ) {
    if ( index < 0 || index >= data.size() ) {
        return;
    }

    data[index].value = value;
}
```

Then inside of your main.cpp file would look like this:

```
Foo foo;
std::cout << "writing cycle of 3" << std::endl;
foo.write_cycle( 3 );
std::cout << "updating index 2 with value of 11" << std::endl;
foo.updateValue( 2, 11 );
std::cout << "writing cycle of 3" << std::endl;
foo.write_cycle( 3 );
```